# Android Application crashes at Button Click

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Once again my silliness has struck. I would like to thank everyone who helped me before hand on my previous issues. I am now to the last thing I want to edit for now.For those that don't know, I am programming an Android application in Eclipse using Java. On this Activity, when I click the calculate button, it crashes and I can't figure out why. I had a similar issue that was a missing bracket in a similar application but I couldn't figure anything out for this one. I swear I looked over the spelling and cases of words and didn't see anything. Knowing me however, that is probably what is going wrong. THANKS!!!

ps. I had no error on my logcat so I don't really know where to start with this. If someone can point me in a direction that might give them something more to go off of, then I would be glad to assist.

Piggy.Java

```
package net.finalexam;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Piggy extends Activity {
    double quartersValue = .25;
    double dimesValue   = .10;
    double nicklesValue  = .05;
    double penniesValue = .01 ;
    double dollarsValue = 1;
    double quartersMoney;
    double dollarsMoney;
    double dimesMoney;
    double nicklesMoney;
    double penniesMoney;
    double totalMoney;
    double newTotalMoney;
    double oldTotalMoney=0;
    int numberOfQuarters;
    int numberOfDimes;
    int numberOfNickles;
    int numberOfPennies;
    int numberOfDollars;



        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView (R.layout.piggybank);
            final EditText quarters =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtQuarters);
            final EditText dimes = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDimes);
            final EditText nickles =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNickles);
            final EditText pennies = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPennies);
            final EditText dollars = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDollars);
            Button calculate =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
            final TextView results = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResults));
            final RadioButton add =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radAdd);
            final RadioButton subtract =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radSubtract);

                calculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    numberOfQuarters = Integer.parseInt(quarters.getText().toString());
                    numberOfDimes = Integer.parseInt(dimes.getText().toString());
                    numberOfNickles = Integer.parseInt(nickles.getText().toString());
                    numberOfPennies = Integer.parseInt(pennies.getText().toString());
                    numberOfDollars = Integer.parseInt(dollars.getText().toString());
                    quartersMoney = numberOfQuarters * quartersValue;
                    dimesMoney = numberOfDimes * dimesValue;
                    nicklesMoney = numberOfNickles * nicklesValue;
                    penniesMoney = numberOfPennies * penniesValue;
                    dollarsMoney = numberOfDollars;
                    totalMoney= quartersMoney + dimesMoney + nicklesMoney + penniesMoney+dollarsMoney;
                    DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.##");

                    if (add.isChecked()){
                        if(totalMoney>0){
                            newTotalMoney =oldTotalMoney +totalMoney;
                            oldTotalMoney = newTotalMoney;
                            results.setText(currency.format("newTotalMoney"));
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(Piggy.this, "You need to do more chores!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }
                    if (subtract.isChecked()){
                        newTotalMoney =oldTotalMoney +totalMoney;
                    }
                        if(newTotalMoney>0){

                            oldTotalMoney = newTotalMoney;
                            results.setText(currency.format("newTotalMoney"));
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(Piggy.this, "Save more money kido!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        ;
                    }
            });
        }

}
```

Here is the Piggy XML to go along with the file. If anyone can see anything I would appreciate your help. I also couldn't figure out the best way to name this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/piggy" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtQuarters"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Number of quarters"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtDimes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtQuarters"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Number of dimes"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtNickles"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDimes"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Number of nickles"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPennies"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtNickles"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Number of pennies"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtResults"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtDollars"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPennies"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Number of Dollars"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDollars"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Add" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radSubtract"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Subtract" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCalculate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Calculate" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit. Thanks guys. This site is really a big help to me and is a great resource. Having said that, I found the error log.

06-21 18:06:25.619: E/AndroidRuntime(26042): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer

Comment: post log when your app is crashing

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the onClick method and execute one line at a time until you find out what line is causing this.

Comment: You **will be getting an error in your LogCat**, to manually debug this is too much effort. Find and post your red LogCat output

Comment: 06-21 18:06:25.619: E/AndroidRuntime(26042): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't fill out one of your EditTexts this will return an empty string `""` attempting to parse an Integer from an empty string will give you a Number Format Exception

You should check first:

```
if(!"".equals(yourString){
   int i = Integer.parseInt(yourString);
}
```

*edit*

You also attempt to do this:

```
 currency.format("newTotalMoney")
```

when you mean to do this:

```
 currency.format(newTotalMoney)
```

*edit 2*

To save yourself some time you should write a method like this:

```
private Integer getNumber(EditText editText){
     int num = 0;
     if(editText == null) {
       Log.e("YouApp", "Didnt find view");
       return num;
     }
     String input = editText.getText().toString();
     if(!"".equals(input)) {
        try{
           num = Integer.parseInt(input);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
          Log.("YouApp", "Invalid input: "+input, e);
        }
     }
     return num;
}
```

Then use it like this in your app:

```
 numberOfNickles = getNumber(nickles);
 numberOfPennies = getNumber(pennies);
 // etc
```

Comment: I tried it again and it still didn't work. But that is somethign to think about for sure... maybe I am still missing something.

Comment: @Chris edited answer, you should really read your LogCat more often

Comment: ok, that second fix DID IT... well kind of.. I still didn't attempt for the fact that it was trying to parse things it cannot. But you got me in the right directino man. Thanks so much.

Comment: well, that didn't completely fix my error. That only fixed it if my I put something in every EditText. I am still tryign to account for the rest.

Comment: @Chris do a check for a blank string when you do `getText().toString()` it's mentioned above

Comment: Thanks, I thought I already clicked answered on here.. my bad.